# How to search an area of the same values in a matrix?

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, matrix

I have a matrix of integers like this:

```
1 1 1 0 3 3 3 0 2 2
1 1 1 0 3 3 3 0 2 2
0 0 0 0 3 3 3 0 0 0 
2 2 0 0 3 3 3 0 4 4
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 0 4 4 4 0
```

where I have different areas of the same value that are separated by "0"s and I need to count how many areas are in the matrix. My algorithm is based on the "0"s and every time a "0" is found a new area is about to come so I increment the counter. The problem is that I search row by row and enter the same area more than once. I only need to count the rectangular areas.

Comment: Showing one example would make your question more understandable.

Comment: How are the matrices stored?

Comment: Are the areas guaranteed to be rectangles?

Comment: the answer for this matrix is 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple, fast algorithm is to iterate over all entries and set each region to zeroes when it is encountered. This takes O(N*M) runtime (each entry visited at most twice) and O(1) additional memory.

To set a region to zeroes, just note the column where it begins, then iterate to the rightmost column. Then iterate over the rows below from the left to right columns, setting each entry to zero.

[Working](https://ideone.com/4Sw4AB) code:

```
int count_regions( int *arr, int rows, int cols ) {
    int region_count = 0;

    for ( int first_index = 0; first_index != rows * cols; ++ first_index ) {
        if ( arr[ first_index ] == 0 ) continue;

        ++ region_count;

        int first_row = first_index / cols, first_col = first_index % cols;
        int last_col;
        for ( last_col = first_col;
              last_col != cols && arr[ first_row * cols + last_col ] != 0;
              ++ last_col ) ;

        for ( int last_row = first_row; 
              last_row != rows && arr[ last_row * cols + first_col ] != 0;
              ++ last_row ) {
            for ( int col = first_col; col != last_col; ++ col ) {
                arr[ last_row * cols + col ] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return region_count;
}
```

Comment: This will work for rectangular entries.  The general version I posted works for entries of any shape.

Comment: @MelNicholson Yep, I made that assumption. Come to think of it, the bitmap fill is easier to compute if you have an original, unmodified copy sitting around…

Comment: could you give me a pseudocode as an example, it would be easier for me to understand

Comment: You modified the input array...  add a copy

Comment: Also, since you modify the array you cannot claim O(1) memory.

Comment: @MelNicholson fixed claim.

Comment: I don't understnad this line 'int first_row = first_index / cols, first_col = first_index % cols;' can't you just flip 0 until you encounter another 0 and that will be your first column and where you should start when you are done painting the area?

Comment: @Buradi 1. that line gets (row,col) indexes from `first_index` which doesn't respect columns. (Doing it this way eliminates a `for` loop around everything, which is just a style issue.) 2. Yes, that is a possible optimization, but it won't make the program much faster.

Answer (score 2):

The painting technique works well.  The idea is that you drop a paint bomb that completely covers an area.  Pseudocode:

```
for (each space) {
  if (space has been painted or is a border) continue;
  else {
    numAreas++;
    drop paint bomb
  }
}
```

And a paint bomb works like this:

```
paint space;
for (each adjacent space) {
  if (space has been painted or space is a border) continue;
  else {
    paint space;
    drop another bomb;
  }
}
```

Comment: in the case i am not allowed to modify the original matrix, is it more convinient to make a copy of the matrix and apply this method or to create another boolean matrix of the same size?

Comment: Creating a boolean matrix of the same size would work.  Copying the matrix doesn't help.

Comment: @Buradi It would be easiest to make your own copy. Converting to Boolean or changing the format entirely could improve efficiency, but would certainly be more work.

Comment: @Potatoswatter the boolean matrix starts as false (unpainted) and each is marked as true when painted.  That avoids the need for specially marking the starting column or making assumptions about the size or shape of the region.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the [*Flood Fill*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm to detect contiguous areas, like this:

Assuming that the initial matrix has only positive numbers,

- Prepare a `counter`, set it to `-1`
- For each point in the matrix:
- If the cell is zero or negative, skip it; otherwise
- Flood fill starting at the cell with the negative value of the `counter`
- Decrement the counter after the flood fill is over

When you reach the end of your matrix, `counter` will have the negative number equal to the number of contiguous numbered areas minus one, i.e. the result that you need is `-(counter+1)`.

Answer (score 1):

I always liked the Union/Find algorithm for isolating groups.  But that's cos I had an old implementation kicking around that I had written years ago.  It's not a big deal to implement, but it might be more appropriate to use Flood Fill.